# how to check if array is emty or full

Tags: java, arrays

i want to check if a array is full and if so print a message and the same thing if its empty?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MeetingFactory {
    Scanner stringScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner intScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public Meeting[][][] calendar = new Meeting[12][31][24];
    private Object MeetingCreator;

    public void MeetingCreator() {
        System.out.println("Enter meeting subject");    
        String input = stringScan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter month");
        int month = intScan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter day of month");
        int date = intScan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter time");
        int time = intScan.nextInt();
        if (!==calendar[month][date][time]()) {
            System.out.println("Another meeting is planned at this time, try other time or day");
            calendar[month][date][time] = new Meeting(input);
        }

        MeetingMenu.Menu();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, this line: `if (!==calendar[month][date][time]()) {` is not valid java code. First of all, Java doesn't support !==, just !=. Besides that, you aren't trying to check the right side variable to anything. Fix that by doing this:

Change this line:

```
if (!==calendar[month][date][time]()) {
```

to:

```
if (calendar[month][date][time] != null) {
```

Comment: This works because if you create an array ob `Object`s, all elements are initialized to `null` in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with 3D matrix, in order for you to check whether the matrix is empty or full, you would need a three nested for loops to check every single cell.

For example to check if the matrix is empty:

```
isEmpty = true;
outerloop:
for(int m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {
    for(int d = 1; d <= 31; d++) {
        for(int t = 1; t <= 24; t++) {
            if(calendar[m][d][t] != null) {
                isEmpty = false;
                break outerloop;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming that `time` will start at 1 and end at 24. Not sure how you exactly want to implement it. And using this logic, you should be able to figure out how to check if matrix is full.